# Как сравнить ответ пользователя без учёта регистра

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, while

Первая задачка. Не пойму чего не хватает.
`user_input` - это переменная, которую вносит пользователь отвечая на вопрос, верно? Т.е. пользователь отвечающий на загадку сам её задает

Как сделать, чтоб дальше программа шла по алгоритму в зависимости от его ответа?
И как сделать, чтоб программа не учитывала регистр ответа?

```
answer = 'Python'
user_input = input('What language do we learn? ')
user_input == answer
while True:
    if True:
        print('Nice')
        break
    else:
        print('Try more')
        break
```

Также не понимаю.
Почему если спрашивать о числах, например:

```
while True:
    users_input = input('Please, input positive number: ')
    if float(users_input) > 0:
        print('Your number is: %s')
        break
    else:
        print('is a wrong number.')
        continue
```

то все нормально, но почему в таком же формате я не могу работать со строками?
Программа все равно идет дальше вне зависимости от того, что отвечает человек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def main():
    answer = 'Python'
    while True:
        user_input = str(input('What language do we learn?\n'))
        if user_input.lower() == answer.lower():
            print('Nice\n')
            break
        else:
            print('Try more\n')
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Примерно так реализуется то, что вы хотите. Метод lower() меняет регистры всех символов строки на нижний. Так удобнее проверять на равенство без учета регистров. Выше дали верный вариант для этой задачи, но если Вы поменяете `answer` 'Python' на 'PYTHON', то Ваш ответ (`user_input`) будет преобразован в 'Python' и не будет равен ответу (`answer`) 'PYTHON'.

Программа не учитывает Ваш ответ, поскольку Вы считаваете его лишь один раз, потом сравниваете с ответом вне цикла, т.е. `user_input == answer` даст вам True/False, которые потом нигде не используются. 
В условии цикла стоит `True`, а не результат Вашего сравнения, соответственно потом программа идет на строку ниже и выполняет первое условие. 
`if True` всегда будет выполняться, так что `else` тут незачем.

Comment: вместо `.lower()`. Для сравнения строк без учёта регистра лучше `.casefold()` использовать. [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/319426/4279)

Comment: не используйте `str()` вокруг `input()` -- это бессмысленно в лучшем случае.

Comment: else и continue здесь не нужны.

Comment: добавлять \n в print() также не нужно (print() и так новую строку добавит)